# Deleting complex object in Java list (for implementation on WSDL)

Tags: java, list, wsdl, iterator, weblogic

I am following those three tutorials and I have completed it with success.
http://oracleadfhowto.blogspot.in/2013/03/create-simple-web-service-using-oracle.html
http://oracleadfhowto.blogspot.in/2013/03/consuming-web-service-using-web-service.html
http://oracleadfmobile.blogspot.in/2013/03/consuming-soap-web-service-in-adf.html

But then, as author haven't implemented removeCountries method I tried to create it.
What I did initially was to just add to class Countries this method:

```
public boolean removeCountry(Country country) {
    return countries.remove(country);
}
```

But although compiler wasn't complaining it didn't work. Actually it worked last night (before reboot) but not today. 
Must be some SOAP iterator/bindig thing or whatever. Or I thought  that it worked but in fact it didn't.

Here are original classes:

```
//-------------------------------
public class Country {
    String CountryId;
    String CountryName;

    public Country() {
        super();
    }

    public Country( String id, String name ) {
        super();
        this.CountryId = id;
        this.CountryName = name;
    }

    public void setCountryId(String CountryId) {
        this.CountryId = CountryId;
    }

    public String getCountryId() {
        return CountryId;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String CountryName) {
        this.CountryName = CountryName;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return CountryName;
    }
}

//----------------------------------
public class Countries {    
    List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();

    public Countries() {
        super();
    }

    public void setCountries(List<Country> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        if ( countries.size() == 0 ) {
            countries.add( new Country("IT","ITALY"));
            countries.add( new Country("IN","INDIA"));
            countries.add( new Country("US","UNITED STATES"));
        }
        return countries;
    }

    public boolean addCountry( Country country ) {
        return countries.add( country );
    }

    // I added this
    public boolean removeCountry( Country country ) {
        return countries.remove( country );
    }
}
//----------------------------------
```

Then I decided to write (for a start) just plain Java classes and now it looks like below shown code.
It works in IDE, not yet implemented on weblogic server. I hope it would work.

```
//----------------------------------
package client;

public class Country {
    String CountryId;
    String CountryName;

    public Country() {
        super();
    }

    public Country(String id, String name) {
        super();
        this.CountryId = id;
        this.CountryName = name;
    }

    public void setCountryId(String CountryId) {
        this.CountryId = CountryId;
    }

    public String getCountryId() {
        return CountryId;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String CountryName) {
        this.CountryName = CountryName;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return CountryName;
    }
}
//------------------------
package client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Countries {

    List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();

    public Countries() {
        super();
    }

    public void setCountries(List<Country> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        if (countries.size() == 0) {
            countries.add(new Country("IT", "ITALY"));
            countries.add(new Country("IN", "INDIA"));
            countries.add(new Country("US", "UNITED STATES"));
        }
        return countries;
    }

    public boolean addCountry(Country country) {
        return countries.add(country);
    }

    // This left unused
    public boolean removeCountry(Country country) {
        return countries.remove(country);
    }

    // I added this - what would be more elegant or smarter way to do this?
    public void removeCountry(String CountryId, String countryName) {

        Iterator<Country> iterator = countries.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Country value = iterator.next();
            if (CountryId.equals(value.CountryId) || countryName.equals(value.CountryName)) {
                iterator.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
//------------------
```

This class is just for test it won't go on server (JDeveloper integrated web logic server)

```
//-------------------------------

package client;

public class UserInterface {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String CountryId = "";
        String CountryName = "";

        CountryName = "ENGLAND";
        Countries co = new Countries();
        co.getCountries();

        for (int i = 0; i < co.countries.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(co.getCountries().get(i).getCountryId());
            System.out.print(" - ");
            System.out.println(co.getCountries().get(i).getCountryName());
        }

        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        // Add some countries
        co.countries.add(new Country("DE", "GERMANY"));
        co.countries.add(new Country("EN", "ENGLAND"));

        for (int i = 0; i < co.countries.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(co.getCountries().get(i).getCountryId());
            System.out.print(" - ");
            System.out.println(co.getCountries().get(i).getCountryName());
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------");

        // Remove some countries, this works but can't use this (index)
        // co.countries.remove(0); <--- there should be some index instead of 0

        // I need to set properties
        CountryId = "DE";
        CountryName = "";
        // Then remove country
        co.removeCountry(CountryId, CountryName);

        CountryId = "";
        CountryName = "ENGLAND";
        // Then remove country
        co.removeCountry(CountryId, CountryName);

        // Is there any way to remove object directly? Parameters should be set by web service iterator.
        // co.countries.remove(o);
        // co.removeCountry(country)

        for (int i = 0; i < co.countries.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(co.getCountries().get(i).getCountryId());
            System.out.print(" - ");
            System.out.println(co.getCountries().get(i).getCountryName());
        }
    }
}
//------------------------
```

I would like to avoid my own iterator as JDeveloper can generate automatically iterators for webservices, but if I can't get it that way, what would be better way to write above mentioned iterator in removeCountry method?

Is there any way to remove object directly with something like this:

```
 co.countries.remove(o);
 co.removeCountry(country)
```

using method

```
// This left unused
public boolean removeCountry(Country country) {
    return countries.remove(country);
}
```

from class Countries?

Parameters should be set by web service iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way, and within "Test Web Service" (with manual inputs of course) it works (I can get, add and remove countries, i.e. objects).

I added this into ConutriesProvider application - which provides web service) into Countries class.

**Is there any better solution than this?**

```
//---------------------
    public boolean removeCountry(Country country) {

        Iterator<Country> iterator = countries.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Country value = iterator.next();
            if (country.CountryId.equals(value.CountryId) || country.CountryName.equals(value.CountryName)) {
                iterator.remove();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
//--------------------
```